# Integrating Multiple Ad Networks on iOS and Android App

Tags: android, ios

I'm the creator of an app (not the developer) and I'm working with a developer to monetize my iOS and Android apps.

My developer says that we cannot ad more than one ad network on an app.

My questions are:

1. Can adMob, Greystrike, appBrain, and AdColony be integrated together on an Android app?
2. Can adMob, iAd, Greystrike, and AdColony be integrated together on an iOS app?

Any advice on ad network combinations to maximize monetization the right way is greatly appreciated.

Comment: In my app i have shown AppNexus Google and startAppAdd at the same time

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No that's not true. You can certainly add more than one ad provider for a single app. There're two ways to do that. Either show different ads at different place or use network mediation.

For the first option you can try interstitial ads, which are basically fullscreen ads and can be shown at loading screens(That looks good in a game, but you'll get bad ratings if it's in a non-game app. Just personal experience). Or you can also use banners of from different networks at different screens of your game.

Now the second option of mediation, is considered better and is relatively easy and less risky. You choose one main network provider and mediate other network provider's ads through the SDK of main ad provider. The priority of the ad provider can be manually set in dashboard, although not all providers give that option. So basically it's decided by fill rate.

I've used Admob mostly for mediation ad banners. It supports a good range of network providers and for non mediation supported networks, you can create custom events too. iAd is supported on admob, Rest of them can be supported using custom events.

Comment: Thanks so much Creator.  I would give you points but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: No issues, I am glad that it helped. Cheers :-)